# Understand Code

Tags: javascript, html

I do not understand the code highlighted below that has a comment *"I DO NOT UNDERSTAND WHAT IS GOING ON HERE*". I know it is a call back function. But I do not understand how the function operates and the purpose. For the record I understand everything else. I have never seen a function written like this before. I do understand that the `OR` statements are for detecting which browser.

```
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>



 window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
   // I DO NOT UNDERSTAND WHAT IS GOING ON HERE
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      console.log("inside callback");
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
  })();
  function drawRectangle(myRectangle, context) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y, myRectangle.width, myRectangle.height);
    context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = myRectangle.borderWidth;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();
  }
  function animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime) {
    // update
    var time = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;

    var linearSpeed = 100;
    // pixels / second
    var newX = linearSpeed * time / 1000;

    if(newX < canvas.width - myRectangle.width - myRectangle.borderWidth / 2) {
      myRectangle.x = newX;
    }

    // clear
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimFrame(function() {
      animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
    });
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  //
  var myRectangle = {
    //position
    x: 0,
    y: 75,
    //dimension
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    // stlye
    borderWidth: 5
  };

  drawRectangle(myRectangle, context);

  // wait one second before starting animation
  setTimeout(function() {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    animate(myRectangle, canvas, context, startTime);
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: The animation is a rectangle moving to the right.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: It's an [OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR).

Answer (score 3):

When you `OR` two values together with JavaScript, you don't explicitly get a boolean... you get back the first truthy value.  This is often used to provide defaults or fallbacks.  For example:

```
console.log( null || 'some string'); // Logs 'some string'


var myOption = 'some value';
myOption = myOption || 'default value'; // myOption is 'some value'
```

What's happening specifically in your code is that the function `requestAnimationFrame` took a long time to be standardized.  Each browser vendor made their own version of it with their own prefix.  This function is going through each possible name of that function until it hits one.  (A function is "truthy" where undefined or null is not.)

Comment: So if it doesnt find the write browser with OR comparison. then it defaults to        function(callback) {
          console.log("inside callback");
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };

Comment: @user2128444 Precisely!